# Facebook OAuth flow on ios for public device

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm working on an ios app targeted for device at public place.

I need the facebook sharing functionality, which means the user login session should be deleted immediately after user finished sharing. But when user login, the log in session is kept in Safari. Although I call logout from app, the user is not actually logged out in browser.
Is there any way to fix this?